# find an element based on class using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a site that contains a bunch of `<input type="text">` tags that are set to 'readonly'. When clicked, I remove the readonly attribute.  In the same click, I also want to display an image with a class of 'saveLink'.

The first part of the click event works...it removes the readonly attribute of the `<input type="text">`.  But the second part doesn't work, it can't find the element with a class of 'saveLink'.

Here's my jQuery:

```
$("body").on('click', '.pageLinks input[type=text]', function () {
    $(this).prop('readonly', false);
    $(this).find('[class=saveLink]').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="pageLinks">
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src='/saveLink.png' class='saveLink' style='display: none;' />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src='/saveLink.png' class='saveLink' style='display: none;' />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src='/saveLink.png' class='saveLink' style='display: none;' />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this?  thanks

Comment: Answers below are correct use `'.saveLink'` but it should be noted capitalization of attributes is supposed to be ignored by html. You should probably change the class to `'save-link'`

Comment: @megawac Attribute names are case-insensitive, but class and id _values_ are case-sensitive. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Case_Sensitivity_in_class_and_id_Names

Comment: Thanks! Did not know that, I had heard that browsers implemented it to be case-sensitive but it wasn't set in spec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$(this).find('[class=saveLink]').css('display', 'block');
```

to:

```
$(this).parent().next().find('img.saveLink').css('display', 'block');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cTq3q/1/)**

Comment: this kind of works, but when clicked, it unhides all the saveLink images, not just the one in the current row. I need it to only display the save image that is closest to the input element that was clicked

Comment: Based on what you posted this should work fine (as the fiddle shows). Do you have more than one input/image set in a containing `<div class="pageLinks">` block?

Comment: Yeah, I have a bunch of textboxes in their own child div beneath the main/parent div(class="pageLinks")

Comment: Can you update the HTML in your question to more accurately reflect what you're really dealing with?

Comment: of course...sorry, I should've done that first, but figured I'd save space and reading time.

Answer (score 2):

Try

[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A8qh6/1)

```
$(this).parent().next().find('.saveLink').show();
```

or

[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A8qh6/)

```
$(this).closest('.pageLinks').find('.saveLink').show();
```

---

References

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 1):

find yes but $('.className')

```
$("body").on('click', '.pageLinks input[type=text]', function () {
$(this).prop('readonly', false);
$(this).find('.saveLink').css('display', 'block');
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
$('.saveLink').css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: Probably because there's more than one `.saveLink`, and he only wants to display the one that's adjacent to the clicked element.